# White Graph Editor Keyframes?

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor

I encountered a really weird problem recently.
I was animating in blender, when all of a sudden my X position was offset. I went into the graph editor to try to fix it, and this is what showed up:
[image]

All my keyframes were white, and I couldn't modify them. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I found out the issue. I had my X curve locked, so I couldn't edit the curves.

Comment: You may want to mark this as "accepted answer", so that this question is actually shown as "answered" on the site.

Comment: @Sybren Note that [self-answers cannot be accepted for 48 hours after they are posted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Every day I learn something new ;-)